# Why does the random forest OOB estimate of error improve when the number of features selected are decreased?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I am applying a random forest algorithm as a classifier on a microarray dataset which are split into two known groups with 1000s of features.  After the initial run I look at the importance of the features and run the tree algorithm again with the 5, 10 and 20 most important features.  **I find that for all features, top 10 and 20 that the OOB estimate of error rate is 1.19% where as for the top 5 features it is 0%.**  This seems counter-intuitive to me, so I was wondering whether you could explain whether I am missing something or I am using the wrong metric.

I an using the randomForest package in R with ntree=1000, nodesize=1 and mtry=sqrt(n)

Comment: Just to be clear: Are you applying RFs in an iterative manner, that is by selecting the top-ranked features (according to Gini index or decrease in MSE) from the whole input space? I know that RFs may not necessarily improve with increasing trees number, but what you are depicting seems to make sense (the best features allow to predict with 100% accuracy the OOB samples), although there is clearly a risk of overfitting when proceeding this way.

Comment: Yes that's what I am doing

Comment: @chl, could you explain why there is a risk of overfitting by using only 5 features?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is feature selection overfit and this is pretty known -- see [Ambroise & McLachlan 2002](http://www.pubmedcentral.nih.gov/articlerender.fcgi?artid=124442&tool=pmcentrez&rendertype=abstract). 
The problem is based on the facts that RF is too smart and number of objects is too small. In the latter case, it is generally pretty easy to randomly create attribute that may have good correlation with the decision. And when the number of attributes is large, you may be certain that some of totally irrelevant ones will be a very good predictors, even enough to form a cluster that will be able to recreate the decision in 100%, especially when the huge flexibility of RF is considered. And so, it becomes obvious that when instructed to find the best possible subset of attributes, the FS procedure finds this cluster.
One solution (CV) is given in A&McL, you can also test our approach to the topic, the [Boruta algorithm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Boruta/index.html), which basically extends the set with "shadow attributes" made to be random by design and compares their RF importance to this obtained for real attributes to judge which of them are indeed random and can be removed; this is replicated many times to be significant. Boruta is rather intended to a bit different task, but as far as my tests showed, the resulting set is free of the FS overfit problem.

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would add an intuitive explanation for this pattern.

In each decision tree comprising the random forest, the data are iteratively split along single dimensions. Crucially, this procedure involves

1) considering only a small, randomly-selected subset of all the explanatory variables, and

2) selecting the most strongly associated explanatory variable *within this randomly-selected variable subset* to split the data along.

Therefore, the probability of the *n* most important variables being selected at any particular node decreases as the number of explanatory variables increases. Therefore, if one adds in a large number of variables that contribute little-to-no explanatory power, it automatically leads to an increase in the forest's error rate. And conversely, choosing only the most important variables for inclusion will very likely lead to a decrease in the error rate.

Random forests are quite robust to this and it typically requires a very large addition of these 'noise' parameters to meaningfully reduce performance.