Is it a good idea to add as many predictors as possible in a random forest?
In a regression context, specification of the regression equation is rather important. When we add predictors to the regression specification which are not relevant can cause a misspecification issue, and therefore hurt the model's accuracy.
I was wondering, whether in the random forest framework this is a big issue? I have many predictors in my dataset, should i include all of them. If no, what is the reason? And how to select which predictors should be included? Thank you!

I've partly addressed this in this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/288762/121522

As for how to select predictors, subject expertise is always helpful.

@mkt This question is not a duplicate and the answer therein is not satisfactory.

Feel free to edit your question to clarify the part that is still unclear or is distinct from the other thread. Note that it requires 3 members of the community to close a question as duplicate, so it's not just me who thought it was covered.
